# ArcGIS Cost Path Analysis. How to extract the area covered by the many possible shortest paths?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cost-path

As you can see in the picture ArcGIS Cost Path Analysis produces different results based on chosen direction (blue path direction: start->stop, red path direction: stop->start).

[image]

As Cost Path Analysis only works in 8 directions, there are many possible shortest paths in the example above. Some of the shortest paths are located in between the blue and the red path. This got me thinking:

**Do you see a possibility to extract the area covered by the many possible shortest paths?**

There are large areas of identical costs in this example. Light colors represent low costs, dark colors reperesent high ones.

Comment: It's a great question.  What does the shading in the map represent--different impedances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is so simple. All you need is a Cost Distance Raster from the start point as well as from the stop point. Just use the Raster Calculator to add these two together and you will get a raster where the value of each cell representing the length of the shortest Cost Path it belongs to. So it is also possible to derive the area of self-defined maximal Path Costs. Path Cost stands in this case for the length of the Cost Path (impedances*path length).

Here you can see the resulting raster according to the map in the question (dark values - high Path Cost, light values - low Path Cost:
[image]

Here I extracted the lowest value of the resulting raster to derive the area covered by the many possible shortest paths (red area):
[image]

EDIT: You can use the [Corridor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/corridor.htm) function to produce this raster.
Well, it has been thought of.  :-)